# Backup multiple virtual machines and save backups to host

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, backup, vmware

I have linux centos server with multiple ( 10 ) virtual machines running on vmware. Is it possible to make backup on database and specific directory on each virtual machine via script and cronjob on host mashine and then save the zips on host machine?

I've tried to search google for such a script or tutorial but no luck on this..